# Confirming conservation laws for complex valued functions

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, complex

Consider the nonlinear Schrödinger equation (I would like to do this for a more complicated set of equations, but to gain understanding I'll consider this simplified case)

$$A_t+iA_{xx}+i|A|^2A =0,$$

where $A=A(x,t)$ is a complex valued function.

One can calculate several conservation laws by looking at the obvious symmetries of its associated action. For instance, we have

$$\frac{\partial |A|^2}{\partial t} +\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} = 0$$

where 
$$P=i(A^*A_x-AA^*_x)$$

Let's say I wanted to check my variational calculus, and make sure this is in fact true, how would I go about doing this in *Mathematica*?

$\textbf{EDIT}$:
I suppose I'll give some code, to try to provoke some interest.

When solving a simple conservation law $f_t+f_x=0$, the following seems to work

```
FullSimplify[D[f[x, t], t] + D[f[x, t], x], 
Assumptions -> {D[f[x, t], t] == -D[f[x, t], x]}]
```

However, when I try something comparable for the conservation law given above, e.g.

```
FullSimplify[
D[u[x, t]^2 + v[x, t]^2, t] - 
2 (u[x, t]*D[v[x, t], x] + v[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x]), 
Assumptions -> {D[u[x, t], 
 t] == -(D[u[x, t], x, x] + (u[x, t]^2 + v[x, t]^2)*u[x, t]), 
 D[v[x, t], 
 t] == -(D[v[x, t], x, x] + (u[x, t]^2 + v[x, t]^2)*v[x, t])}]
```

where I've written $A=u+iv$, for $u,v$ real functions. This doesn't yield any type of simplification. In fact it just returns

```
2 (v[x,t] ((v^(0,1))[x,t]-(u^(1,0))[x,t])+u[x,t] ((u^(0,1))[x,t]-(v^(1,0))
[x,t]))
```

i.e. no simplification.

$\textbf{Edit 2}$: My algebra was incorrect, this method works in Mathematica using Assumptions.

```
FullSimplify[
D[u[x, t]^2 + v[x, t]^2, t] - 
2 D[(u[x, t]*D[v[x, t], x] - v[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x]), x], 
Assumptions -> {D[u[x, t], 
 t] == (D[v[x, t], x, x] + (u[x, t]^2 + v[x, t]^2)*v[x, t]), 
D[v[x, t], 
 t] == -(D[u[x, t], x, x] + (u[x, t]^2 + v[x, t]^2)*u[x, t])}]
```

Comment: Congratulations on solving your problem.  Any idea on how bounty works in the event that you write up your Edit 2 as an answer?

Comment: @bb: OP will not get the invested rep back even if he answers his own question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following may be slightly more direct than the approach given in the answer. I don't split up the wave function into real and imaginary parts, so I can work with the original equations, making it easier to spot errors.

The equation I want to check is `eqn`, and the equation of motion is `nLS`. I use two *different* function names for $\psi$ and its complex conjugate: `ψ` and `ψStar`. This avoids trouble with derivatives of the `Conjugate` function. I'll print out the intermediate results so you can see that every step remains close to what you would do by hand:

```
eqn = 
  D[ψ[x, t] ψStar[x, t], t] + 
    I D[(D[ψ[x, t], x] ψStar[x, t] - ψ[x, 
          t] D[ψStar[x, t], x]), x] == 0
```

> $$i \left(\psi ^{(2,0)}(x,t) \text{$\psi $Star}(x,t)-\psi
>    (x,t) \text{$\psi $Star}^{(2,0)}(x,t)\right)+\psi
>    ^{(0,1)}(x,t) \text{$\psi $Star}(x,t)+\psi (x,t)
>    \text{$\psi $Star}^{(0,1)}(x,t)=0$$

```
nLS = 
 D[ψ[x, t], t] == -I D[ψ[x, t], x, x] - 
   I ψ[x, t]^2 ψStar[x, t]
```

> $$\psi ^{(0,1)}(x,t)=-i \psi ^{(2,0)}(x,t)-i \psi (x,t)^2
>    \text{$\psi $Star}(x,t)$$

```
nLSstar = 
 nLS /. {ψ -> ψStar, ψStar -> ψ, 
  Complex[x_, y_] -> Complex[x, -y]}
```

> $$\text{$\psi $Star}^{(0,1)}(x,t)=i \psi (x,t)
>    \text{$\psi $Star}(x,t)^2+i \text{$\psi
>    $Star}^{(2,0)}(x,t)$$

```
Simplify[eqn, Assumptions -> (nLS && nLSstar)]
```

> `True`

In `nLSstar`, I form the complex conjugate of the equation of motion, by directly exchanging the functions and reversing the sign of $i$. Using the the result in the `Assumptions`, `Simplify` is able to verify the claim.